# How to make a python program one-time use?

Tags: python

Is there anyway to construct a python program such that, after using it once, that specific program will no longer be usable on *any* computer? If so, how?

Note that I'll be compiling the program into a .exe, in case that makes things easier.

Comment: What would you define as 'same program running twice'?

Comment: Say I have a file called "PacMan.exe". I run the program, have a great time playing, and then close it. The next day, I come back to it and run it, but the program blocks me from accessing the game some how, as I've already gone on it once.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: If you want to have running the program disable only that copy? Well, the simple answer is to have the program delete itself. However, you run into the fundamental problem of copy protection: the user can just make copies of the program and run them separately, or even back up his computer before running the program and then restore the backup to get around any tricks you might try with hidden files or registry settings. Ultimately, all you can do is make it difficult to run the program twice, not impossible.

---

Have the actual code run on a server, and have the script simply send a request to the server asking that the program be run. The server can ignore any requests after the first.

Without a central server? There's no way. One guy running a program on his computer can't disable the program on everyone else's computers unless the programs communicate in some way. Even then, if the logic resides in the script, it's not too difficult to simply disable the checks.

Comment: I'm aware of copy protection, but like I said to @Blender, I'd prefer an insecure way to no way.

Comment: @Sim: Like Blender said, have the program leave a secret note for itself somewhere, in the registry or AppData or something. If it sees the note when it starts up, it can abort.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. I can load script into a virtual machine, save the state of the machine, and then reset the virtual machine every time I want to run the script.

Plus, executables generated by Py2exe, cx_Freeze, PyInstaller, etc. are easy to disassemble into your *original* source code, so someone wouldn't even need to go as far as a virtual machine to break your restrictions.

I would just make it into a webapp and have users purchase access tokens. The software runs entirely on your server, so they have nothing to disassemble.

---

If you don't really care about security, just add some key to the registry or make a file in AppData that is checked before the script is run.

Answer (score 1):

Distribute only a downloader with a URL with a unique key. Set up the server to only allow downloads from authorized keys (obviously, make the keys hard to guess) and to disable a key upon successful download.

Hire and set up response staff to react 24/7 to customers who insist they should get another go because lightning struck just as they finished downloading, or whatever. For evil karma points, team up with the MPAA and have them unleash their hoards of paralegal attack monkeys on any such customers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know python, but seems you need TWO programs. The first is a launcher, the other - your main program that you want to work only once - is loaded by the launcher, and deleted/deformed after it executes by the launcher itself, so it would never work again. I'm thinking as a windows programmer, as i'd do it  with an exe-dll pair though... my answer might not be applicable to python.

Answer (score 0):

python used to have crontab modules https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/

perhaps at the end of your python script you can get the time, such as:

```
from datetime import datetime
str(datetime.now())
```

and then create a crontab to execute a different script in the very near future and overwrite your python file them rm it.  Or on Windows have the python create a batch file that does the same thing, but sleeps for sometime in the beginning, run the batch file from Python and then soon enough, that can be the end of your .py.